# Searching files in directory using regex and grep

Tags: regex

So I have to find every file in the /etc directory that start with a,b or c

what i have is: `grep -l '/^[a-cA-C].*/g' /etc/*` though i keep getting every file in the /etc directory.

I use `grep -l`to get every file (I guess using `find` or `grep` doesn't matter

`'/^[a-cA-C].*/g'` to find everything that starts with a,b or c uppercase or lowercase followed by zero or more characters ending with a global search so it doesn't stop after the first match

I know the regex is right cause i've checked it with a regex-checker online.

EDIT: found the solution --> ls /etc/[a-cA-C]*

Comment: You'd use the command 'ls' rather than 'grep', to find files in a directory.  The 'ls' command does not take grep's regular expressions, instead it takes arguments that the shell uses it's own "pattern-matching" to expand to a file list - see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern for example. EDIT: Ooops, sorry  - did you mean files whose CONTENTS start with 'a', 'b' or 'c'?

Comment: I mean if there is a file in /etc directory which names start with a,b or c. For example apple.txt it has to return it but if there is a file named windows.txt it should not return the windows file.

Comment: Great - then my original comment applies, so use the 'ls' command with the patterns in that link :)

Answer (score 0):

Here my example:

```
find ./ -type f -exec basename {} \; | grep -Ei '^(a|b|c)'
```

It search recursively and find all files, but return in output only `basename` of file, is it ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
find | grep '^\./[abc]'
```